# phonegap application telephone links using a tags opens up InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am developing a hybrid app using jquery mobile 1.2 and cordova 2.4. There are a number of static pages that have phone links like this one:

```
    <a href="tel:0312345678"> 03 1234 5678</a>
```

Clicking on these type of links is causing a default behaviour of opening up InAppBrowser's web view that sts on top but inside the app. It is being treated as a normal url.

Is there any way to avoid this and just open up only normal call prompt dialog but not the web-browser inside the app? I can't seem to find any solution to this.

Any help would be much appreciated.